# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR when accessing webpack DevServer sub-URLs from a different machine

Tags: express, ssl, webpack, https, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to access my web application served using the webpack DevServer from a virtual machine, but I'm able to connect through HTTPS only to the main URL - all sub-URLs fail with `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` error.

#### Here is my setup:

I'm running webpack DevServer on a host machine with macOS. My virtual machine is running Windows 10 (VMware Fusion in bridged network mode). Webpack DevServer uses custom self-signed SSL certificates (generated using the [`mkcert` tool](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert)).

Here is my DevServer configuration (`@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server`):

```
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "admin:build",
            "allowedHosts": [
              "localhost",
              "admin.local.slido-staging.com"
            ],
            "host": "0.0.0.0",
            "port": 443,
            "servePath": "/",
            "ssl": true,
            "sslCert": "ssl/server.crt",
            "sslKey": "ssl/server.key"
          },
```

(`local.slido-staging.com` is just a "DNS alias" for `localhost` due to internal requirements, so the development certificate is also generated for `*.local.slido-staging.com`).

To make the web app accessible over HTTPS also from the virtual machine, I've exported the root certification authority (generated by `mkcert`) from the host machine, imported it to the root certificate authorities store on the VM Windows machine and added `192.168.2.90  admin.local.slido-staging.com` to my Windows `hosts` file (192.168.2.90 is the IP address of my host machine).

#### The problem:

The web app is perfectly accessible from the host machine - HTTPS works for the main URL `admin.local.slido-staging.com` and also for sub-URLs (e.g. `admin.local.slido-staging.com\main.js`, see the screenshots:
[image: Host machine 1]
[image: Host machine 2]

But, when I try to access it from the VM, only the main URL (`admin.local.slido-staging.com`) loads through HTTPS, all other sub-URLs/resources end up with `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`:
[image]
[image]

Here is another strange thing - trying to access any sub-URLs from the VM by entering the IP address of the host machine instead of the hostname works (an HTTPS connection is initiated, although the certificate doesn't match that name/IP address as expected), but trying to access it through the hostname fails (ignore the 4443 port on the last screenshot - I was just trying to serve the app from a different port):
[image]
[image]

What could be the problem? I spend a few hours debugging it, but without success (I tried also the `-disable-host-check` param for the DevServer, it didn't help)

### Update:

I tried to serve the app using HTTP instead of HTTPS and it also doesn't work in the web browser - just the error message changed from `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` to `ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE`. But Wireshark shows that some data were fetched [image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by the latest version of [Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/security/anyconnect-secure-mobility-client/index.html) (4.10) installed on the host computer. After downgrading Cisco AnyConnect software to version 4.9 everything works as expected.